# OutBound Email adn Audience Manger - Manage Address book - Tridion 2011

Tags: 2011, outbound-email, audience-manager

Tridion version : Tridion 2011 
Request :
We need different business units send out newsletters under same publication using different ( address book, mailing list and distributions )

I know this request is out of the box which tridion does not support as part of ( Outbound email and Audience Manager).

We have a request for newsletter publishing.

we need to create two address books for two different user groups and restrict access to them not to import contacts, 
which we can achieve using the rights and permissions.

but when any of the groups create mailing list they see ( general,address books, distribution list and Info) tabs.

Is there a way when the user create the mailing list , we load only the address books for which the user have access on the Available Address Books Even though both this address books are added to the publication Level.

Example :

TEST Publication
   -> Audience Manager
      -> UAT USER GROUP 1 Address Book ( Access to User Group 1)
      -> UAT USER GROUP 2 Address Book( Access to User Group 2)

When user create a mailing List and select the Address Book Tab can we restrict

scenario 1) When User Group 1 Login in and create mailing list ( UAT USER GROUP 2 Address Book ) should not be listed under Available Address Books

scenario 2) When User Group 2 Login in and create mailing list ( UAT USER GROUP 1 Address Book ) should not be listed under Available Address Books .

[image: mailing list add address book]

Comment: Can you confirm you have set the explicitly removed the read permission for a specific group against a specific book (although they have Publicaiton level Permissions Management and Contact Management Rights explicitly remove 'Read' permissions on the Address Book)

Comment: Thanks mark for the response, Yes the default read permission is removed. I created two groups and two address books and i have given read/ write access only to the specific group. But the issue here is when I create the mailing list for the first time all the address book created and associated on the pub level is shown on the selected Address Book. The editor needs to move all the address book from selected  address book to Available Address Book.  How can we avoid this and display only the Address book on the Available address book based on the User Group. Is this even possible on same pub

Answer (score 1):

When you say

> we **load** only the address books for which the user have access on
>   the Available Address Books Even though both this address books are
>   added to the publication Level.

I assume you mean show in the panel in your image above. Given that, according to [SDL Documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B1B3B9B9-0497-4148-9865-60D253C5460E)  is seems that your first ask is possible *to be able to restrict access to an address book*.

Perhaps you have to explicitly 'deny' access if you're finding it's applied by virtue of being a member of a group that already has "*Read permissions on the Address Book*".

If I understand your second part - you then want to do 'something' with the list(s) that are legitimately listed; be that filter them, auto select one/all you could get creative:

- Use a GUI extension to assess the Groups to which this user is assigned - and map this to the address-book name (using some sort of naming convention just as _Book A [group-1, group-3] )

  - the same GUI extension could remove the [ ] element and place it into some type of `data-` HTML attribute to keep the GUI clean
  - of course the quickest way here is DOM manipulation so there is a risk of a flash of more than they should see - you could opt to disable the books they can't use rather than remove to avoid too much visual interference